# Where do I start looking for cause of SIGSEGV in main.m line 15

Tags: ios, objective-c, segmentation-fault

I have an app in the App Store that is giving the following error message:

> SIGSEGV in main.m line 15

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));  <-- line 15
}
}
```

The pertinent user's particulars are:

[image]

and this is the stack trace:

```
0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x3b446b26 0x3b443000 + 15142
1 UIKit 0x3376c03b 0x33549000 + 2240571
2 UIKit 0x3376bf43 0x33549000 + 2240323
3 UIKit 0x3367132b 0x33549000 + 1213227
4 UIKit 0x33724253 0x33549000 + 1946195
5 UIKit 0x335d4971 0x33549000 + 571761
6 UIKit 0x3354c473 0x33549000 + 13427
7 CoreFoundation 0x30dae1d5 <redacted> + 20
8 CoreFoundation 0x30dabb79 <redacted> + 284
9 CoreFoundation 0x30dabebb <redacted> + 730
10 CoreFoundation 0x30d16ce7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
11 CoreFoundation 0x30d16acb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
12 GraphicsServices 0x359e4283 GSEventRunModal + 138
13 UIKit 0x335b8a41 UIApplicationMain + 1136
14 SalonBook 0x0006c0f5 main (main.m:15) + 28917
```

Any ideas of where to start looking for the cause of this error?

Comment: Have you run the static analyzer on your code to look for memory management issues?

Comment: No... but using XCode 5, I have watched the memory usage in the Debug Navigator, and it's nothing out of the ordinary (6.3 mb).  It looks like it didn't even get to the first view controller, according to the stack trace.

Comment: What is the unit of measurement for appMemTotal, which is 42.4...?

Comment: Have you been provided with console logs associated with this crash?

Comment: Yes, I saw that, and iPads have log files as well. Log files from the device(s) affected might have more details about the problem.

Comment: I can't get to the log because it's on the user's iPad and I don't know who he/she is.  I found out that AppMemTotal refers to the total memory used by the application on the time of the crash. Will find out if it's K or Mb.

Comment: AppMemTotal refers to Mb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is hitting a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault), or a memory access violation. A 42 MB memory footprint sounds large, based on the jettison logs I have seen from my own devices in the past year or so. I don't know anything about your app, what kind of resources it has in memory, etc. There's a range of memory problems your app could have:

- simple excessive demand for memory that can't be met (there is no swap file)
- retain cycle causing unnecessary memory pressure
- invalid pointer access

The goals I recommend you achieve with your app:

- Achieve zero warnings reported by the analyzer
- Determine under what circumstances memory allocations get that high
- Identify and eliminate retain cycles
- Identify resources that are in memory unnecessarily and get rid of them
- Identify resources that are larger than they should be and rework them

The starting point for investigating this problem is to run Xcode's analyzer via the **Product > Analyze** menu item. This will detect and report known causes of memory access errors. If you are not using Automatic Reference Counting, it will also report potential memory leaks. As of this writing, I don't believe the analyzer helps with retain cycles.

Next, simply use your app on a device, running via Xcode, and watch the memory footprint. As you navigate through the app and/or use more features, is memory usage simply growing and never shrinking? Identify any scenarios that cause large increases in memory footprint. Again, I don't know your app, so I don't know how to provide more specific guidance at this point.

A retain cycle can be evident if you use the allocations instrument in Apple's [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) app. You run this via the **Product > Profile** menu item. Instruments allows you to browse allocations by object type, size, count, etc. and allows you to see call stacks for individual objects so you know how they were created. You might find that some allocations jump out at you, e.g. "What is this image that's 4 MB?" or "Why does the app have 8000 NSArray objects?" Another task that Instruments helps with here is providing generations. The "Mark Generation" button lets you place markers at key points within a workflow. Before and after the workflow is performed, you will see the amount of memory growth in that timespan, and you can drill down into the call stacks to see what is getting allocated and how.

If you have questions about any of this, please leave a comment and I'll follow up when able.

Comment: I think I found the memory leak... I have various UIPopovers; for some reason, ARC is not releasing the storage.  What do I do to resolve this?  I have noticed that it mainly happens in Germany... maybe the translation?  I check on that...

Comment: It could be a retain cycle. A UIViewController typically retains a UIPopoverController that it creates so it can be dismissed later. If the UIPopoverController in turn retains the UIViewController, or is not otherwise dismissed, that's a problem. I can't guess on why Germany would be specifically affected.